# Dealing with HttpResponse in unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, webforms, httpresponse

I have a simple website that has one page. The function I am unit testing is

```
public void WriteFileToClient(string fileContent, string fileName)
        {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            stringWriter.Write(fileContent);
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.txt", fileName));
            Response.Clear();

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            }
            Response.End();
        }
```

When I run my test it says that `Response` is not available [image]

Here is my Unit test

```
[TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Unit")]
        public void WriteFileToClient_ShouldSucceedForCorrectInput()
        {
            //Arrange
            Migrate migrate = new Migrate();
            Guid g = Guid.Parse("fffe49c1-a838-46bc-b5c6-4e0bbd3e4c32");

            string fileContent = migrate.GenerateFlatFileText(g);
            string fileName = string.Format("flat file - {0}.txt", g);

            //Ask
            migrate.WriteFileToClient(fileContent, fileName);

            //Assert
            migrate.Response.OutputStream.Should().NotBeNull();
            migrate.Response.ContentType.Should().Be("text/plain");
            migrate.Response.Headers.Should().HaveCount(1);
        }
```

Any suggestions on how to mock the response? honestly I don't understand why the `Response` object is not available, my `Migrate` class inherits `Page` and to my understanding should has the `Response` included

Answer (score 3):

The Response object is part of System.Web, which is a strong indicator it runs inside a web server. You are running a "unit test" on web code without invoking a web server. Can you guess why it might be failing?

UI is not normally something you can easily unit test, if at all. An exception is a controller in MVC, but the controller must be isolated from dependencies to be unit tested beyond "did it call the correct view". When you start dealing with tests on things like response stream, you need to bring up the code in the context of a web server. This means the actual code with Response has to be tested using an HTTP Request and then examining the response. This is more of an integration test than a unit test, unless you mock up the dependency.

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Gregory, This make sense. In my unit test I am calling functions that live in a context of a web server which fails because I am not in a web server context anymore. Do you suggest to mock up the dependency or move on  and test my functions using `HttpRequest` to that page?

Comment: In most cases, I use very thin UI bits. Example: ASP.NET page has events that are a few lines at most and the actual moving code is in classes. But, I don't move code that writes to the stream deeper, as it is very UI focused. You then separate the types of tests based on what you are testing. If you are testing web UI, it is more likely integration testing. Make sense?

Comment: It does, I think I need some time to wrap my mind around it